# Reference Object Through Its Implemented Generalized Interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have a converter interface that looks something like this:

```
public interface MyTypeConverter<T>
{
  public MyObject toMyObject(T obj);
  public T fromMyObject(MyObject mo);
}
```

I also have an implementation of that interface:

```
public class ABCTypeConverter implements MyTypeConverter<ABCObject>
{
  public MyObject toMyObject(ABCObject obj)
  {
    ...do conversion...
  }
  public ABCObject fromMyObject(MyObject mo)
  {
    ...do conversion...
  }
}
```

And a factory that evaluates the objects type, and returns an appropriate converter implementation:

```
public class MyTypeConverterFactory
{
  public static MyTypeConverter<?> create(Object source)
  {
    if ( source instanceof ABCObject )
      return new ABCTypeConverter();
    ...and so on...
  }
}
```

Now the problem I am having is in referencing the Factory's returned converter instance by using the interface:

```
MyTypeConverter<?> converter = MyTypeConverterFactory.create(someObject);
MyObject mo = converter.toMyObject(someObject);
```

The last line gives me the following compile-time error:

```
The method toMyObject(capture#3-of ?) in the type MyTypeConverter<capture#3-of ?> 
  is not applicable for the arguments (ABCObject)
```

So how could I reference the converter in a generic fashion?

**EDIT**

The core of my question is: How do I call a method on an interface reference without first casting to the underlying concrete type? And if I can't, then what is the point of creating a generic interface to begin with? I.E., How do I do this (regardless of how I get the reference):

```
MyTypeConverter<?> converter = MyTypeConverterFactory.create(someObject);
MyObject mo = converter.toMyObject(someObject);
```

Without first casting "converter" to its underlying concrete type?

Answer (score 0):

### This is a total anti-pattern approach to the FactoryMethod Pattern:

```
if ( source instanceof ABCObject )
  return new ABCTypeConverter();
...and so on...
```

Don't do that it will never scale and will never be maintainable.

What is wrong with:

```
TypeConverter<ABCObject> tc = new TypeConverter<ABCObject>();
```

That is how every sane framework that implements something like this works.

For example:

[com.google.common.base.Converter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Converter.html)

Look at the how Jackson does it for JSON Serializer/Deserializers as well.

There is a way with Guava to get an instance of a type `T`

```
Class<T> klass = (Class<T>) new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {}.getRawType();
```

Then you can do `klass.newInstance();` but this is hacky was well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **Polymorphism** as well instead of making it **Generic**.

Just return the interface reference instead of actual object reference from factory's `create()` method. At run-time the actual object decide what method should be called based on **overridden method** logic.

---

In below sample code I have created an interface `MyTypeConverterObject` that is implemented by all the classes that are part of  `MyTypeConverter` interface.

Now simply return `MyTypeConverterObject` from factory's `create()` method.

Sample code:

```
interface MyTypeConverterObject {}

class ABCObject implements MyTypeConverterObject {}
class XYZObject implements MyTypeConverterObject {}

class MyObject {}

interface MyTypeConverter {
    public MyObject toMyObject(MyTypeConverterObject obj);
    public MyTypeConverterObject fromMyObject(MyObject mo);
}

class ABCTypeConverter implements MyTypeConverter {
    public MyObject toMyObject(MyTypeConverterObject obj) {
        return new MyObject();
    }
    public MyTypeConverterObject fromMyObject(MyObject mo) {
        return new ABCObject();
    }
}

class MyTypeConverterFactory {
    public static MyTypeConverter create(Object source) {
        if (source instanceof ABCObject) {
            return new ABCTypeConverter();
        }
        return ...;
    }
}
```

---

A Factory method should return product of same type i.e. product that implements same interface.

For example: A car factory can return cars of different type but can't produce bike.

[image]

[image]

If you need to return different type of products then use **Abstract factory**.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is in lines 2 and 3: I don't have control over the vendor-provided classes ABCObject and XYZObject, so I can have them implement a common interface.